# How do I find and use my imported modules?

Tags: python, import, module, pycharm, pythonpath

I am very new to python, and this is one of my first projects. I now use PyCharm, but started with Anaconda and jupyter notebook. When i try to import a module into my project, i get this error:

```
import stdiomask
stdiomask.getpass('Password: ')

/Users/Kristoffer/.conda/envs/Prosjekt_beginner/bin/python "/Users/Kristoffer/Desktop/Pycharm prosjekter/moduler/modultest.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Kristoffer/Desktop/Pycharm prosjekter/moduler/modultest.py", line 1, in <module>
    import stdiomask
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'stdiomask'
```

After searching the internet for answers, I am still lost, but suspect it has something to do with my pythonpath. Anaconda might also have something to do with it. As I said I just started with python, so I do not know whether this is enough information to solve my problem, but this is what i did:

Checking if the module is installed with both pip and pip 3:

```
(base) KKWs-MBP-2:~ Kristoffer$ pip install stdiomask
Requirement already satisfied: stdiomask in ./opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages (0.0.6)


(base) KKWs-MBP-2:~ Kristoffer$ pip3 install stdiomask
Requirement already satisfied: stdiomask in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages (0.0.6)
WARNING: You are using pip version 20.2.3; however, version 20.3.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/python3.9 -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

And then i checked which version of python I am using and got two different answers.

```
(base) KKWs-MBP-2:~ Kristoffer$ python
Python 3.8.3 (default, Jul  2 2020, 11:26:31) 
[Clang 10.0.0 ] :: Anaconda, Inc. on darwin

(base) KKWs-MBP-2:~ Kristoffer$ python3
Python 3.9.0 (v3.9.0:9cf6752276, Oct  5 2020, 11:29:23) 
[Clang 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)] on darwin
```

I then typed in this in PyCharm and got:

```
import sys
print(sys.path)

/Users/Kristoffer/.conda/envs/Prosjekt_beginner/bin/python "/Users/Kristoffer/Desktop/Pycharm prosjekter/moduler/modultest.py"
['/Users/Kristoffer/Desktop/Pycharm prosjekter/moduler', '/Users/Kristoffer/Desktop/Pycharm prosjekter/moduler', '/Users/Kristoffer/.conda/envs/Prosjekt_beginner/lib/python38.zip', '/Users/Kristoffer/.conda/envs/Prosjekt_beginner/lib/python3.8', '/Users/Kristoffer/.conda/envs/Prosjekt_beginner/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload', '/Users/Kristoffer/.conda/envs/Prosjekt_beginner/lib/python3.8/site-packages']
```

Comment: The directory where your packages were installed is different than the interpreter used by pycharm. Activate your conda env, then use `python -m pip install stdiomask`

Comment: print(sys.version) to get python version

Answer (score 0):

So As You Said You are using Anaconda So when you are doing `pip3 install stdiomask` or `pip install stdiomask` you are installing it on your real python enviroment & as you mentioned you are using anaconda enviroment,

so give this command `conda install stdiomask`
Or visit This [Website](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/tasks/install-packages/) And Read...

I Hope it Helped

**Jai Hind Jai Bharat**

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, when using `pip` or `pip3` to install packages, these are python modules, but also binaries, and using them like:

```sh
pip install <package>
```

or

```sh
pip3 install <package>
```

Doesn't explicitly tell you which interpreter `pip` is pointing to. However, executing a module using `python -m <module>` uses the `python` in your path, and *is* explicit. You've already seen that the `pip -V` site-packages is different than your interpreter's site-packages. The way to get around this is to use `pip` as a module:

```sh
python -m pip install <package>
```

Then you *know* that you are using the python that you currently have activated

Comment: I tried to install the module using python -m <module> but still got the same result. I think the problem might be my path. I downloaded Anaconda Navigator awhile ago, but have switched to PyCharm recently (not through Anaconda). Could it be that my path is set to the python version connected to Anaconda Navigator? And if so how do I change it?  Again, I am very new to this so I am sorry if what I say does'nt really make sense. This is what I got when I tried to use python -m pip install <module>:
(Next comment)

Comment: (base) KKWs-MBP-2:~ Kristoffer$ python -m pip install stdiomask
Processing ./Library/Caches/pip/wheels/c1/e9/4e/bcdfc282cffe91bb88e951ad9a05fb166ed6460bbe3c6dc02b/stdiomask-0.0.6-py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: stdiomask
Successfully installed stdiomask-0.0.6

Comment: Ensure that you've activated your conda environment with `conda activate <your_environment>` before attempting to `pip` install